# Magento 2 Product Export Problems "Please correct the data sent value"

Tags: magento2, product, export

Magento 2 Version 2.1.1 -  I am intermittently getting the error "Please correct the data sent value." when trying to export product.

**Test results:**

> Full Export no filter = Fail Filter by Country of Origin "A" = Pass
>   (976 Product Lines) Filter by Country of Origin  "B" = Fail (Approx
>   8000 Product lines) Filter by Attribute (from above fail) = Pass (2
>   Product Lines) Filter by Categories = "Fail" (Various Product lines
>   from 4 to 500)

Some products are configurable most are simple.

I previously had problems with my imports due to spaces in file names for Images which caused breaks in the import process and consequently random upload issues on affected product on the Store Front. (Pages failed to load).

Since then i have successfully imported my entire 10K item store with no issues, but i now cannot export reliably.

PHP settings are well beyond what's required. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additional in Error file: main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. 
main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively.

Comment: Try to debug these lines of code : `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GetFilter.php:39` , `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php:61` amd `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php:58` in order to retrieve the root cause.

Comment: NB: Just upgraded to 2.1.5 and no change to the problem.

Comment: can you share the exception throw from the files i listed to you?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did remove all log file in var (or you can backup it) then re-run export function. After that go to var/log and found an exception.

Open log and see that function

```
set_time_limit
```

I go to php.ini and found that the function in list disable function config. I remove it from list then it works.

You can visit here for more detail: https://community.magento.com/t5/forums/replypage/board-id/magento-2-technical-issues/message-id/1575